# how can integrate the javadoc with a project

Tags: java, javadoc, opencv3.0

my codes can be shown as follows, however when doing that net beans says that the relevant javadocs are not in libraries. Please help me to solve this problem. how can I integrate javadocs with libraries.please reply me soon

```
import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.CvType;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer this link to get your [javadoc](http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/) .But when compared to previos version (OpenCV 2.4.10) it's not well constructed.

In NetBeanse IDE,

1. Go to Tools Tab
2. Select "Java Platforms"
3. You will see Java Platform Manger Window
4. Select the tab "Javadoc"
5. from the right side select the "**Add URl**" button under the "ADD ZIP/Folder"
6. Copy and paste the Javdoc URL mentioned above

[image: Click "Add URL" to finish]

And for more instructions for download the javadoc to read offline , [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986993/how-to-download-javadoc-to-read-offline)

Hope This helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. I got the answer