# Is there any documentation for OpenCV 3.0 on Java?

Tags: java, opencv, javadoc

In my company we're starting to experiment with OpenCV 3.0 on Java (with Eclipse), to learn the fundamentals of digital image processing. Unfortunately, apart from a couple of tutorials we're unable to find any real documentation for OpenCV 3.0 on Java. Of course, the javadoc for 3.0 is available at this address http://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/ but it's pretty much empty, so it's useless to link it as javadoc in eclipse.

I've seen this topic on stackoverflow:

[How to download or link OpenCV Javadoc in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30700719/how-to-download-or-link-opencv-javadoc-in-eclipse)

where they basically say that for OpenCV 3.0 there doesn't seem to be any real documentation out there, but the topic it's a little outdated, so maybe there are some news?

I've seen that there's a decent javadoc for OpenCV version 2.x, but nothing for OpenCV 3.

Apart from the original documentation (for the c++ version of OpenCV), what's the best source of information for OpenCV 3.0 on Java?

No need to say that it's quite time consuming/far from efficient to use the original c++ documentation while using Java..

Comment: How about https://opencv-java-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/?